# Filter for jar-file by analyse with findbugs

Tags: file, jar, findbugs, build.xml

I have a jar-file, which I want analyze with findbugs through build.xml. I use "class location =....jar" - pattern. The jar-file contains several folders, but I need to analyze only one folder. How can I specify that ? Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a filter file, a filter file can say what file patterns to include, exclude among other things... There's documentation here http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/filter.html

Answer (score 0):

There is a patch for findbugs that adds support for nested filesets. You can probably combine this with Ant's `zipfileset` to filter the folder you want.

The patch is on [the findbugs sourceforge page.](https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=2883928&group_id=96405&atid=614695)